# Correct way/sequence to create DbContext

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework-6, dbcontext

What is the correct way to generate a DbContext for my database. (I'm using *database first*.)

It looks like the *EF 6.x DbContext Generator* option generates empty files if I don't first create an *ADO.NET Entity Data Model* (EDMX file).

However, if I create the EDMX file first and then create the DbContext, I seem to get conflicting symbols with errors such as:

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'BillsEntities.BillsEntities()' and 'BillsEntities.BillsEntities()'

And

> d:\users\jonathan\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\BillTracking\BillsDomain\BillsModel.Context.cs(23,33,23,48): error CS0111: Type 'Entities' already defines a member called 'OnModelCreating' with the same parameter types

And

> d:\users\jonathan\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\BillTracking\BillsDomain\BillsModel.Context.cs(28,36,28,41): error CS0102: The type 'Entities' already contains a definition for 'Bills'

And

> d:\users\jonathan\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\BillTracking\BillsDomain\BillsModel.Context.cs(29,39,29,47): error CS0102: The type 'Entities' already contains a definition for 'Payments'

And

> d:\users\jonathan\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\BillTracking\BillsDomain\BillsModel.Context.cs(30,39,30,48): error CS0102: The type 'Entities' already contains a definition for 'Utilities'

If that's not enough, I notice every time I generate a new EDMX file it seems to want to create a new connection string in my config file and doesn't seem to give me an option to use the existing one.

Can anyone point me to a resource that provides an example of performing these tasks in the correct way and the correct order? When I Google on this, mostly what I get is code-first articles that don't address this at all.

Comment: Are you configuring the EDMX to generate the entities to project different than the project containing the EDMX? If so that can be a reason for the duplicate classes. The generation will create the classes both in the project containing the EDMX and your other target project the first time. You can then delete the .tt files under your .edmx file (in Solution Explorer) and they will not be re-generated on subsequent code gens.

Comment: @user469104: No, I created a separate domain project and all my database models, EDMX, and entites go in that domain project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the correct way to generate a DbContext for my database. (I'm using database first.)

If you are using database first, you will need to and ADO.NET Entity Data Model.

> It looks like the EF 6.x DbContext Generator option generates empty files if I don't first create an ADO.NET Entity Data Model (EDMX file).

You shouldn't be running any of these commands if you are using database first:  Enable-Migrations, Add-Migration, Update-Database. Your first step is to create the EDMX file.

> However, if I create the EDMX file first and then create the DbContext, I seem to get conflicting symbols with errors such as:

Once you create your EDMX file, your DbContext will also be created within the file. You can access this file by expanding your edmx file followed you by your .Context.tt and open up your .Context.cs class. Notice how the constructor for this class contains a :base("name=yourdbEntities"), which can be found in your web.config file.

> If that's not enough, I notice every time I generate a new EDMX file it seems to want to create a new connection string in my config file and doesn't seem to give me an option to use the existing one.

Comment out your connection string and let it create a new one when you create your edmx file. If all is well, you can come back and delete it.

Here are a couple of resources you may find helpful:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/entity_framework/entity_database_first_approach.htm
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o-cV_fSNMqw

I hope you find this answer helpful.

Comment: Yes, it does appear that the DbContext classes are already created without running any of the other commands. Perhaps this changed over the past few years. Testing further.